# Change file field to assets field without losing the selected image

Tags: assets, file-uploads

Does Assets keep the same content when changing from a file field?
I just wanted to be sure on this.

Thanks,
Diederik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does - I've done this many times. Just make sure you're using the latest version of Assets.